# ios - Hide a view but still enable user interaction on it

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, ios11, arkit

TL;DR: Is it possible to hide a view but keep the interaction on it enabled?

The case I'm facing is that I'm running an AR session with a AR SceneView which allows for the user to drop blocks and other items onto the screen. I also am able to render this AR SceneView to a video. My issue is that while I'm rendering the video, my AR objects seem to speeding up. I've determined that this is a problem with the renderer forcing the sceneview to speed up to the rate at which it's generating images.

I have access to these images and figured a decent solution would be to display an ImageView and hide the sceneview while I'm recording, so that I can constantly update the image view with the latest snapshot from the AR, but the issue with that becomes that I can't click on my AR SceneView anymore to add objects to the AR Scene. So if I can hide the sceneview but still allow touches on it that would essentially fix my problem.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding the view why dont you set the background color to clear

Comment: The ARSceneView doesn't seem to respond to setting a background color for it. I know that with SceneViews you can, but with the AR it just uses the input it receives from the camera